# how to get each dataframe's name after the datatframe was splited?

Tags: r, knitr

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(knitr)
df <- tibble(
  letter = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = TRUE),
  nums = rep(1:10, 10),
  a = rnorm(100),
  b = rnorm(100),
  c = rnorm(100),
  d = rnorm(100)
)

df %>%
  split(.$letter) %>%
  map(~ group_by(., nums) %>%
        summarise(a = sum(a)) %>%
        kable(caption = paste("it is table", substitute(.)))
      )
```

As the code above show, I want to set the caption something like "it is table a", "it is table b" ... after the datatframe was splited.

Comment: You may need `format = "latex"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this need to be a single `%>%` pipeline? Otherwise you can easily do it in two steps:

```
summarized <- df %>%
  split(.$letter) %>%
  map(~ group_by(., nums) %>%
        summarise(a = sum(a)))

lapply(names(summarized), function(letter)       
     kable(summarized[letter], caption = paste("it is table", letter)))
```

Markdown tables, however, do not have captions in `kable()`. Use `format="html"` or `format="latex"` to get an output format that supports captions.